# Ninject: GetAll instances that inherit from the same abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance, dependency-injection, ninject, abstract-class

Is it possible for Ninject to get all instances that inherit from a specific Abstract Class? For example, I have the following Abstract Class.

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass { }
```

Then I have the following two derived classes that both inherit from the same abstract class.

```
public class MyDerivedClass1 : MyAbstractClass { }

public class MyDerivedClass2 : MyAbstractClass { }
```

Now I am going to bind both derived classes with the Kernel because I want them to be in singleton scope.

```
_kernel = new StandardKernel();
_kernel.Bind<MyDerivedClass1>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
_kernel.Bind<MyDerivedClass2>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

I know the Kernel can return me an instance like the following.

```
_kernel.Get<MyDerivedClass1>();
```

Is there a way to get all of the classes that inherit from MyAbstractClass? I tried the following without success.

```
IEnumerable<MyAbstractClass> items = kernel.GetAll<MyAbstractClass>();
```

The hope was that the above GetAll() method would return a list of two instances, one would be MyDerivedClass1 and the second would be MyDerivedClass2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of creating two bindings, the second one with a "redirect" to the first, what you can also do is:

```
_kernel.Bind<MyAbstractClass, MyDerivedClass1>()
       .To<MyDerivedClass1>().InSingletonScope();
_kernel.Bind<MyAbstractClass, MyDerivedClass2>()
       .To<MyDerivedClass1>().InSingletonScope();
```

This expresses the intention more clearly.

Comment: Thank you that did the trick with less code! Is it possible to create this kind of singleton binding for all classes that inherit from MyAbstractClass automatically? Maybe some combination of Ninect and Reflection that would find all concrete classes that inherit from MyAbstractClass?

Comment: @eric yes. You can se [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions) for this. If you need more info, there's probably already a question on SO covering it or a similar scenario. If not you can, of course, post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you're binding only to the implementation type, not the base class type, with `ToSelf`. It's effectively calling `_kernel.Bind<MyDerivedClass1>().To<MyDerivedClass1>()`

To bind the implementation types to the base type use:

```
_kernel = new StandardKernel();
_kernel.Bind<MyAbstractClass>().To<MyDerivedClass1>().InSingletonScope();
_kernel.Bind<MyAbstractClass>().To<MyDerivedClass2>().InSingletonScope();

//returns both
var allImplementations = _kernel.GetAll<MyAbstractClass>();
```

EDIT: Multiple bindings to singleton.

```
_kernel = new StandardKernel();
_kernel.Bind<MyDerivedClass1>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
_kernel.Bind<MyDerivedClass2>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();

_kernel.Bind<MyAbstractClass>().ToMethod(x => _kernel.Get<MyDerivedClass1>());
_kernel.Bind<MyAbstractClass>().ToMethod(x => _kernel.Get<MyDerivedClass2>());
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the InSingletonScope is working as expected. When I call _kernel.GetAll<MyAbstractClass>() I can see the constructor being called for MyDerivedClass1 and MyDerivedClass2 as expected, but when I call _kernel.Get<MyDerivedClass1>() I see its constructor being called again. I would hope that this Get<T>() call would just return the current instance of MyDerivedClass1 created from the GetAll<T> call.

Comment: `_kernel.Get<MyDerivedClass1>()` is looking for the instance/type bound to `MyDerivedClass`. Ninject is a little annoying to use the same instance for multiple bindings. See my edit for this.

Answer (score 0):

So if you need to have a singleton inherited from abstract class and to use it via GetAll or Get, it works like this:

```
public abstract class Test
{
    public string Name;
    public Test(string s)
    {
        Name = s;
    }
}

public class T1 : Test
{
    public T1() : base("T1")
    {
    }
}

public class T2 : Test
{
    public T2() : base("T2")
    {
    }
}
```

Then:

```
    static StandardKernel kernel;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel(new LoadModule());    

        var tests = kernel.GetAll<Test>();
        tests.ToList().ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(c.Name));
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(GetByType<T1>().Name);
        var z = GetByType<T1>();
        z.Name = "abc";           
        Console.WriteLine(z.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(GetByType<T1>().Name);

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(GetByType<T2>().Name);
        var za = GetByType<T2>();
        za.Name = "abc";
        Console.WriteLine(za.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(GetByType<T2>().Name);

        Console.WriteLine();

        tests = kernel.GetAll<Test>();
        tests.ToList().ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(c.Name));
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadKey();



    }

    static public T GetByType<T>()
    {
        return kernel.Get<T>();
    }

    public class LoadModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {    
            this.Bind<Test, T1>().To<T1>().InSingletonScope();
            this.Bind<Test>().To<T2>();

        }
    }
```

Output as expected:

```
    T1
    T2


    T1
    abc
    abc

    T2
    abc
    T2

    abc
    T2
```