# Ninject: Construct all classes that inherit from an abstract class that also pass some custom Boolean logic

Tags: ninject

I am looking to find out how to use Ninject to get all instances that inherit from a base class that also pass some custom Boolean criteria. This is a continuation of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465091/ninject-getall-instances-that-inherit-from-the-same-abstract-class). This is how I am creating a binging for all classes that inherit from MyAbstractClass.

```
_kernel.Bind(x => { x
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom<MyAbstractClass>()
    .BindAllBaseClasses()
    .Configure(syntax => syntax.InSingletonScope());
});
```

If I have the syntax correct, this will create a singleton scope binding for all classes that inherit from MyAbstractClass. Next I need to get/construct all the classes.

```
IEnumerable<MyAbstractClass> items = kernel.GetAll<MyAbstractClass>();
```

The code above will get/create all classes that inherit from MyAbstractClass.

Now I need to add one more step to this process. Based on “access roles” not all classes that inherit from MyAbstractClass should be created because the current user might not have access to functionality for every derived class. So I tried adding a CanLoad Boolean to each derived class and tried the following.

```
IEnumerable<MyAbstractClass> items = kernel.GetAll<MyAbstractClass>().Where(x => x.CanLoad == true);
```

While items did contain only the classes I expected, based on my CanLoad logic, I did see the constructor for each derived class being called because of the kernel.GetAll() method. Also it will have to create the class to call its CanLoad method, so that will not work. I thought about making the CanLoad static too. I also thought about a method that would look similar to the following.

```
public bool CanLoad<T>() where T : MyAbstractClass {
    //return true if the current user has the correct access roles to create class of type T
}
```

So my question is how can I use the Ninject GetAll() method to get all classes that inherit from MyAbstractClass that also return true for the CanLoad Boolean method? I have been trying to use Ninject and Linq and possibly Reflection but I do not have a solution yet.

**Edit:**

To elaborate on the “permission logic”, at the very beginning our app calls out to a web service to get a list of LDAP groups/roles which are returned as a simple list of string. Each of the derived classes are actually ViewModels and each ViewModel “needs” a minimum role for its functionality to be usable by the current user. I thought I could tie the Ninject/binding/get logic with some custom “permission logic” and only bind/get classes the current user has access to. The list of VMs become an ItemsSource binding for a docking control (and we are considering using creating an ItemsSource binding for the Ribbon control as well). It’s all research at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `When` constraint to the binding:

```
.Configure(syntax => syntax
    .When(... check permission here...)
    .InSingletonScope());
```

Since you didn't say anything about the logic how you know whether the user has permission, i can't give you more specific information here. But generally speaking, you should add a 'When' constraint to your binding whenever you want to make sure it cannot and will not be instanciated unless a condition is met.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to get the When syntax to work based on a simple test. Ninject did not create a binding for specific classes that inherited from MyAbstractClass but these classes can still be created by Ninject if the Get<T>() method is called directly. That is why I was initially looking at the GetAll<T>() and Get<T>() methods.

Comment: @Eric that's because your using `.BindAllBaseClasses()`. The class itself is not a base class. To bind exactly `MyAbstractClass` and the concrete type you can either implement an 'IBindingGenerator' and use 'BindWith<>' or you can use `BindSelection(ServiceSelector)` where the `ServiceSelector` delegate returns the variable `type` and `typeof(MyAbstractClass)`. Then it also works if you disable the option that ninject will also create concrete classes which don't have a binding.